# PHP Language : While/For loops, better performance?

Tags: php

Which loop is better between for and while loop ?

I need to know it for performance optimization.

Thank's a lot.

Comment: You get the best performance if you unroll all your loops.

Comment: The difference over the code's entire lifetime, if any, would be less than the amount of time you spent writing a question about it.  If your code's too slow, this ain't the reason.

Comment: For loops are executed faster from a benchmark I have done with an array of 300k, but you must take into account array indexes...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using :

`array array_map ( callable $callback , array $array1 [, array $... ] )`

is better from both.

```
<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

This makes $b have:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 125
)
```

Comment: how does this answer the question? he asked about two different kinds of loops, iterating over an array wasnt even mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Do not try to tune performance on such a low level, write good and clean code and choose the loop that fits your use case. There will be no significant performance difference between `for` and `while` anyways, but that does not change the philosophy: do not butcher your code to tune performance.

Answer (score 0):

None is better. You shouldn't even think about such base constructions performance. If you use loops right way, all would be good enough.